# Cannot view data in hive partition table

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have a external table that has a partitioned column called rundate. I can load data into the table using

```
DataFrame.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).orc("s3://test/table")
```

I then create a partition using

```
spark.sql("ALTER TABLE table ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION(rundate = '2017-12-19')")
```

The code works fine and i can see the partitions. But I cannot see data in the Hive table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not saved the partition data in correct folder structure and also manually added the partition where data does not exist.

Two things:
1. First make sure you are saving at data at the location where external table is created and also the folder structure is same as hive expect. e.g Assume your external table name is `table` and partition column is `rundate`, partition value is `2017-12-19` and external table is pointing to location `s3://test/table`. Then save data for partition `2017-12-19` as below:

```
DataFrame.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).orc("s3://test/table/rundate=2017-12-19/")
```

2.Once save is successful below command to update the metastore of hive with the latest added partition.

```
synatx: msck repair table <tablename>
msck repair table table
```